# Iterative storing items to corresponding files by a given instruction

Tags: bash

I want to perform sorting items to corresponding files by a given instruction.

The instruction is in `instruction.txt`:

```
item_1    file_5
item_3    file_2
item_6    file_7
item_22   file_2
...
item_m    file_n
```

Items are stored in a `contents.txt`:

```
>item_1
blablas
bla
>item_2
blas
...
>item_m
bla
bla
bla
```

I want the procedure to read the instructions for each item, go to the contents file and extract an item with its contents (including `>item_*`, excluding next `>`) and append to the corresponding `file_**`and save it as `file_**_upd`.

Would be grateful for the assistance!

P.S. some files belong to same files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -we '
    open my $instruction, "<", "instruction.txt" or die $!;
    my %where = map split, <$instruction>;
    open my $contents, "<", "contents.txt" or die $!;
    my $out;
    while (<$contents>) {
        open $out, ">", $where{$1} if /^>(.*)/;
        print {$out} $_;
    }'
```

- [open](http://p3rl.org/open) opens a file, "<" means *for reading*, while ">" means *for writing*.
- The diamond operator `<>` reads from the file handle, see [readline](http://p3rl.org/readline).
- The pairs from instructions are saved to an associative table `%where` (see also [map](http://p3rl.org/map) and [split](http://p3rl.org/split)).
- The `contents.txt` is read line by line, if a line starts with `>`, a new output file is created. The file handle of the output is declared outside the loop, so it survives its iterations, so all lines after a `>` are printed to the same file.

*Update:* To handle multiple items per file, and also to output items with no file assigned, you need to a bit more work:

```
perl -we '
    open my $instruction, "<", "instruction.txt" or die $!;
    my %where = map split, <$instruction>;
    open my $contents, "<", "contents.txt" or die $!;
    my $out;
    my $unknown = "file_unknown";
    my %created;
    while (<$contents>) {
        open $out, $created{ $where{$1} // $unknown }++ ? ">>" : ">",
             $where{$1} // $unknown if /^>(.*)/;
        print {$out} $_;
    }'
```

The hash %created keeps track of already created files, so they are appended rather than overwriten next time. The defined-or operator `//` is used to output items with no file assigned to `file_unknown`.

Comment: Hi, you solution is cool but it doesn't work properly if there are several items belonging to one file_* - in this case, the script only adds the first occurrence to the resulting file. How can it be fixed?

Comment: @PolinaNovikova: Updated.

Comment: for a non-professional in Perl that seems cool, thanks, it works!